What does "pick up" mean in "frog season is really starting to pick up"
I'm playing a video game that is entirely written by a single person born in Auburn, Washington. When I walk up to one of the characters in the game he utters this single line to me:
"frog season is really starting to pick up"
What does "pick up" mean in this context?
Some of the definitions I found that might fit this context on Oxford Learners Dictionary:
1.become better; improve.
"my luck's picked up"

become stronger; increase.
"the wind has picked up"

resume something.
"let's pick up where we left off yesterday"



"become stronger; increase.". That, basically. It's really hard to pin down exactly what it means here, but it's increasing

Increase in some way.  What is "frog season"?

If I said "Tourist season is really picking up" it would mean the number of tourists in the area is markedly increasing. Hotels are full, restaurants have few empty tables, there are lines at the museums, more boats on the lake, more bodies on the beach, whatever.

The problem here is that frogs live for quite a number of years, so "frog season" is a really ambiguous phrase. "Breeding season" would be ok, because it's annual, but you can't just say "frog season"

I've got it 

pick up is synonymous with ramp up

Here "pick up" means something like the first or second definitions, indicating some type of an increase in intensity or frequency. Without more context, it's not clear exactly what about frog season is picking up.
The phrase could be used to suggest that the person is starting to have more luck catching frogs (assuming that's what you do during frog season) - "[my luck during] frog season is really starting to pick up". It might instead indicate that more people have begun participating in frog season - "[the number of people out during] frog season is really starting to pick up".  It might indicate that there are more frogs out during frog season, or that there are better deals on frogs, or more places to buy them, or really any increase in some characteristic feature of "frog season". Whatever particular aspect of frog season the speaker is referring to, there is a trend toward there being more of it, but in general, we can say that frog season is "ramping up".
